# Can someone tell me what kind of bicycle this is? Also, how much would it be worth?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Can someone tell me the make, model, and value of this bicycle?

The logo on the front says **IMPERIAL** in white across a gold (or silver?) band over a black circle with four gold crowns in an arch across the top with four small red dots above each, and four four-pointed gold stars across the bottom.

[image: Logo]

[image: Full bicycle picture]

Underneath the saddle there's a "BMA/6 certified" sticker.

[image: More pictures]

Comment: We don't do valuations sorry - a bike is worth what someone will pay for it, and that varies depending on location and availibility, and how much more effort is needed to make it safe to ride.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting bike.

It shows low-end one-piece cranks, but reasonably nicer U brakes instead of the standard calipers.  The calipers look original because of the way the inner cable is mounted.

The handlebars have been rotated upward a ridiculous and unsafe amount - that can be fixed by slacking off the pinch bolt/s in the stem and rotating it back down then retighten.

The bike has sissy-levers on the brakes on the bars, and an enormous metal spoke protector on the rear wheel.

I would suspect its a 1980s bike, possibly from the bike booms inspired by the oil crisis.  If you don't want it, donate to your local bike cooperative, or give it to someone who will fix and use it.

Comment: Thank you for replying! 